# Unable to install python module in ubuntu

Tags: python

I tried to install some library using below command
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

and getting below error..

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main zlib1g-dev i386 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main libmysqlclient-dev i386 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.1/libmysqlclient-dev_5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_maverick_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Tried for `sudo apt-get update`
It is also giving similar error.
Please help, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What error is `sudo apt-get update` giving you?

Comment: Ubuntu Maverick has been end of life since April 2012. You should upgrade to a newer version if possible.

Comment: Isn't maverick EOL? I can't find archives for this. In any case, this this would be off-topic.

Comment: @maggotbrain It is, but this got migrated over from SO, so they wouldn't really know about that. ;) Long answer short: Maveric repos are no longer active, because it's EOL.

Comment: @FEichinger right. We've got many 404 dupes. Just need to find one. ;-)